# How to Keep the Debug Console Docked in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019

How can the debugger be kept docked in Visual Studio 2019? It currently opens a command prompt pop-up window.

This is the way it pops up. How can it show like the docked Output window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to this, in the options window search for `console`.
Then in the category ASP.NET Core you will find the setting `Run web server in`. This setting has 2 values:

- `External Console`
- `Integrated Terminal`

As the setting category indicates this only applies to ASP.NET Core projects.

[Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YbVE.png)